# Issues Rotating X,Y Coordinate on Cartesian Plane

Tags: c++

I am currently attempting to rotate a scatter plot theta degrees about an origin. Following my previous post, I am using the two sets of equations found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix

Note: This differs from my previous post, as this post addressed how the implementation of the equations is not working.

However, after applying the equations, it is not rotation about the origin at all.

Here is my current code:

```
//Loop through all points
for (int playerEntity = 0; playerEntity < 13; playerEntity++) {

    //x and y coords for point
    int px;
    int py;

    //If rotation angle requires counter clockwise (- degree) rotation
    if (theta< 0) {

        //Load point from scatter plot relative to origin
        px = positionX[playerEntity] / 20;
        py = positionY[playerEntity] / 20;

        //Convert the degree rotation to radians
        double rad = (theta*3.1415) / 180;

        //Apply Counter Clockwise rotation equations
        px = px * cos(rad) - py * sin(rad);
        py = py * cos(rad) + px * sin(rad);
    }
    else {
        //Load point from scatter plot relative to origin
        px = positionX[playerEntity] / 20;
        py = positionY[playerEntity] / 20;

        //Convert the degree rotation to radians
        double rad = (theta*3.1415) / 180;

        //Apply Clockwise rotation equations
        px = px * cos(rad) + py * sin(rad);
        py = py * cos(rad) - px * sin(rad);
    }


     //Define origin
     int originX = 1000;
     int originY = 500;

     //Graph points (Note it subtracts py, as negative y values make it plot upwards and positive y values make it plot downwards
     colorPixel(originX + px , originY- py);

}
```

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: I had an answer, but when I implemented the equation, they are not working

Comment: The line "py = py * cos(rad) - px * sin(rad)" needs the *previous* value of px, not the one that was changed right before. You need to introduce intermediary variables px2, py2, compute them using the formula, then copying them to px,py (in the current state, you are "sawing the branch on which you are sitting" in a certain sense.

Comment: Yup! Thanks for your response! That was exactly what I needed to do. I wasn't even considering that when looking for the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in

```
    px = px * cos(rad) - py * sin(rad);
    py = py * cos(rad) + px * sin(rad);
```

When you calculate the new `py` you are using the already transformed `px`.
Just do something like this:

```
    float px_new = px * cos(rad) - py * sin(rad);
    float py_new = py * cos(rad) + px * sin(rad);
    px = px_new; py = py_new;
```

I'm also not sure why you need the `if` branch for negative `theta`. If you always want to rotate clockwise, just write `theta = std::abs(theta);` (but that's likely not what you want).

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much! I had been looking at this for two hours and hadn't even realized that stupid mistake. It is much more efficient to use this than my way anyways, even if I had corrected the tangent error in my result.

Comment: The if-branch is in fact wrong. It calculates a clockwise rotation over `-rad` radians, which happens to be a _counter_ clockwise rotation over `rad` degrees.